# Determine whether a swipe event is for a left swipe or a right swipe

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I am using Angular 2 and ionic 2 and am trying to capture left and right swipes. I can capture a swipe but can't work out how to determine if it is a left or right swipe.

In my html I have:

```
<ion-content (swipe)="swipeEvent($event)">
```

This calls `swipeEvent` every time a swipe occurs.

My `swipeEvent` javascript code looks like this:

```
swipeEvent(event){
        alert('swipe');
    }
```

How can I determine if it is a left or right swipe.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It looks like the gestures are built on top of [HammerJS](http://hammerjs.github.io/) as stated in the [Ionic 2 docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#gestures).

> You can target specific gestures to trigger specific functionality.
>   Built on top of Hammer.js...

When you trigger a swipe event an object gets passed to the bound method it contains an option `e.direction` which is a numeric value corresponding to a swipe direction.

Below is the list of direction constants which are defined [here](http://hammerjs.github.io/api/#constants) in the HammerJS docs

> ```
>    Name              Value
> DIRECTION_NONE         1
> DIRECTION_LEFT         2
> DIRECTION_RIGHT        4
> DIRECTION_UP           8
> DIRECTION_DOWN         16
> DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL   6
> DIRECTION_VERTICAL     24
> DIRECTION_ALL          30
> ```

**Example**

Given your `ion-content` setup

```
swipeEvent(e) {
    if (e.direction == 2) {
        //direction 2 = right to left swipe.
    }
}
```

**Useful tip**

Alternatively (doesn't look like Ionic have covered this in their gestures doc), you can use [HammerJS events](http://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-swipe/) in the HTML tag to target a specific swipe direction.

```
<ion-content (swipeleft)="swipeLeftEvent($event)">
```

Only found this out by trial and error and it seemed to work for most events!

Comment: I too discovered (swipeleft) by trial and error. I am sure it will be documented eventually.

Comment: They more than likely will do, what i've noticed is (swipeleft) and (swiperight) work but (swipeup) and (swipedown) dont.

Comment: ok, when i swipe left to right almost value is 4, but some time is 1 or 8, what does 1 and 8 mean ?

Comment: Click on the direction constants link in my answer and find out ;)

Comment: @Will.Harris Thanks a lot. Your suggestion worked just perfect in my app.

Comment: @Will.Harris this custom gesture provider will enable vertical swipes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42650832/1467810

Comment: works good but what about DIRECTION_NONE  1... what is the meaning of swip to direction none?

Comment: For Ionic4 to work `npm install hammerjs` first, then go into `main.ts` and add the line `import 'hammerjs';` that way hammerJS will be loaded, to utilise the swipe event methods.

Answer (score 3):

html

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
  <ion-title>Main</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-content padding class="main">
    // height: 300px; background-color: #000;  => visible for test
    <div (pan)='swipeEvent($event)'></div>
</ion-content>
```

typescrip

```
export class MainPage {
    constructor(public nav: NavController) { }

    swipeEvent($e) {
        // swipe left $e.direction = 2;

        // pan for get fired position
        console.log($e.deltaX+", "+$e.deltaY);
    }
}
```

if deltaX > 0 swipe right else swipe left.
i like to use `pan` instead of `swipe` because i want to make a slide image same as [Scrollyeah](http://artpolikarpov.github.io/scrollyeah/examples/parallax.html)

Answer (score 2):

You cab bind separate event handlers with Ionic, like:

```
<ion-content on-swipe-left="onSwipeLeft()" on-swipe-right="onSwipeRight()">
```

You may also use `on-swipe` like:

```
<ion-content on-swipe="swiped($event)">

$scope.swiped = function($e) {
  var what = '';
  switch ($e.gesture.direction) {
    case 'up':
      what = 'Swiped up';
      break;
    case 'down':
      what = 'Swiped down';
      break;
    case 'left':
      what = 'Swiped left';
      break;
    case 'right':
      what = 'Swiped right';
      break;
    default:
      what = 'Swiped ???';
      break;
  }
  alert(what)

}
```

Using Ionic 2

```
<ion-content (swipe)="swipeEvent($event)">


swipeEvent($e) {
  var what = '';
  switch ($e.gesture.direction) {
    case 'up':
      what = 'Swiped up';
      break;
    case 'down':
      what = 'Swiped down';
      break;
    case 'left':
      what = 'Swiped left';
      break;
    case 'right':
      what = 'Swiped right';
      break;
    default:
      what = 'Swiped ???';
      break;
  }
  alert(what)
}
```

[Ionic Docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/onSwipe/)

Comment: on-swipe-left only works with ionic 1 I am using ionic 2. I will change my question to mention I am using ionic 2

Comment: Ionic 2 doesn't have $scope.

Comment: the second approach not work on ionic 2: ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'direction' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Just to update - as of Ionic 3.19.0, functionality is as follows:

```
<div (swipe)="swipeEvent($event)" />
```

and

```
swipeEvent($e) {
    if($e.offsetDirection == 4){
        // Swiped right, for example:
        this.week.prevWeek();
    } else if($e.offsetDirection == 2){
        // Swiped left, for example:
        this.week.nextWeek();
    }
}
```

Also - an even quicker inline solution, if you're only concerned with left and right swipes:

```
<div (swipe)="($event.direction === 4) ? calendar.back() : calendar.forward()" />
```