# Swipe up/down not working on Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, ionic2, hammer.js

How can I use `swipe up` or `swipe down` with Ionic 2?

I've tried the [Gestures API](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#gestures) but it only fires on horizontal swipe.

```
<ion-card (swipe)="swipePage($event)">
</ion-card>
```

Answer (score 13):

In the HammerJS official document, bottom line says :

> When calling Hammer() to create a simple instance, the pan and swipe
>   recognizers are configured to only detect horizontal gestures.

For additional config, you must tweak your hammer instance, try this :

> First run `npm install hammerjs --save && npm install @types/hammerjs --save-dev`

```
import { HammerGestureConfig, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import * as Hammer from 'hammerjs';

// create a class that overrides hammer default config

export class MyHammerConfig extends HammerGestureConfig  {
  overrides = <any>{
    'swipe': { direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL } // override default settings
  }
}

// In your module providers, add this :

providers: [{ 
  provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, 
  useClass: MyHammerConfig 
}]
```

Comment: works great for me, 1 suggestion is that adding new library into package.json will help maintain your libraries.

Comment: Worked flawlessly in an Angular 4 + Ionic 3 project.

Comment: Ionic 2 project, worked great.  `HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG` is not used as a quick note

Comment: I've been looking so hard for this. Just works. Thanks!

Comment: Btw, `Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL === 30` so if you don't want to install the entire library and types you can avoid it by doing this. You can also reference the other constants [here](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/blob/a28c530297f6e66785476013a6c9162305a2ce42/src/inputjs/input-consts.js)

Comment: Instead of installing hammerjs or hard coding the direction this works in Ionic 3: { direction: window['Hammer'].DIRECTION_ALL }

Comment: Example swipe up/down usage in template: <div (swipeUp)="doSomething()" (swipeDown)="doSomething()">

Answer (score 0):

**For Ionic 5+,**

Install Hammerjs using `npm install --save hammerjs @types/hammerjs`

Then, on `app.module.ts`, HammerModule and BrowserModule like so:

```
import { BrowserModule, HammerModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Then, within the imports array, add HammerModule, and of course, BrowserModule that comes as default.
Like so: `imports: [BrowserModule, HammerModule,...]`

Then, go to `main.ts` file and add `import 'hammerjs';`

If your project is being served using `ionic serve`, disconnect it and reconnect, to initialize your update.

To call the swipe events on your page, use (pan) or (swipe) events like so:

```
//home.page.html
<div (pan)="swipeEvent($event)"></div>

//home.page.ts

swipeEvent(e){
   swipeDirection = e.direction;
   console.log('Swipe',swipeDirection);
   //2 = left;
   //4 = right;
   //8 = top;
   //16 = down;
}
```